# Cocoapods: force latest version download

Tags: cocoapods

There is a library I'm using in a project whose podspec is very outdated. As a result, my project seems to be pulling in older files. The library in question is Classy: https://github.com/ClassyKit/Classy

The podspec, which mentions version 0.2.4, has not been updated since 2014. The actual version, however, has some necessary fixes (such as https://github.com/ClassyKit/Classy/pull/97/commits) that come after the podspec update. Rather than moving things around manually, I'd prefer to have cocoapods handle it to make sure the files are in-sync. Problem is that whenever I run "pod update" it claims that the repo is up-to-date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple solutions

You can automatically target latest commit for a specific branch:

```
pod 'Classy', git: 'https://github.com/cloudkite/Classy.git', branch: 'master'
```

You can automatically target latest commit with a head specifier (credit to [Stalin Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4754996/stalin-kay)):

```
pod 'Classy', git: 'https://github.com/cloudkite/Classy.git', commit: 'HEAD'
```

You can manually target today's latest commit, in order to *freeze* your integration to a specific commit:

```
pod 'Classy', git: 'https://github.com/cloudkite/Classy.git', commit: 'c319908f8bded62e268dfd48ee5d65329b819129'
```

---

#### Cloning alternatives

You can clone the repo, update the .podspec (simply remove reference to tag and set version to '0.0.1'), and target your own repo in Podfile:

```
pod 'Classy', git: 'https://github.com/atsepkov/Classy.git'
```

or same thing and target your own .podspec:

```
pod 'Classy', podspec: 'https://github.com/atsepkov/Classy/blob/master/JSONKit.podspec'
```

To give you an example, this is exactly what I did here: https://github.com/Coeur/Classy/blob/master/Classy.podspec.

You can also create your own source of your .podspec files, and add the source of it:

```
source 'https://github.com/atsepkov/Specs.git'
pod 'Classy'
```

Or you can push your .podspec to CocoaPods trunk under a new name:

```
pod trunk push ClassyByAlexanderTsepkov.podspec
```

---

#### Old CocoaPods

If you are using CocoaPods 0.39.0 (but it will not work for 1.0.0+ anymore), you can directly use the `head` command:

```
pod 'Classy', :head
```

---

#### What will not work

If you target the repo directly, you will be using the latest .podspec of that repo (but that's not enough for your case):

```
pod 'Classy', git: 'https://github.com/cloudkite/Classy.git'
```

---

#### Contact author

Finally, consider contacting the podspec owner https://twitter.com/cloudkite

Comment: Thanks, going through your solutions but still seem to be encountering some difficulties. It looks like `:head` option has been removed, `:git` by itself still pulls a stale version, `:commit` by itself causes an error, but git + commit check out the desired version, but now I started seeing an odd error about xcode not being able to find the header files (and not just for Classy), Pods/Headers directory is empty and I can't figure out if it's a result of the new options or something else, removing the options didn't fix the problem, and I'm still debugging it now.

Comment: In newer versions of cocoapods (Specifically 1.3.1, this might also work on earlier versions but I haven't tested it.), instead of `pod 'Classy', :head` you can try `pod "Classy", git: https://github.com/cloudkite/Classy.git', branch: 'master', commit: 'HEAD'`